# CreateObject("Lotus.NotesSession") eventually fails with Cannot create ActiveX component

Tags: vb.net, lotus-domino

I have the following VB Code interacting with Lotus Notes:

```
Dim objNotesSession As Object = Nothing ' Domino.NotesSession = Nothing
Dim objNotesDatabase As Object = Nothing 'Domino.NotesDatabase = Nothing
Dim objNotesDocument As Object = Nothing 'Domino.NotesDocument = Nothing
Dim objNotesRichTextItem As Object = Nothing 'Domino.NotesRichTextItem = Nothing
Dim objNotesItem As Object = Nothing 'Domino.NotesItem = Nothing

Try
    objNotesSession = CreateObject("Lotus.NotesSession") 'New Domino.NotesSession
    objNotesSession.Initialize(Password)
    objNotesDatabase = objNotesSession.GetDatabase(Server, Database)
    objNotesDocument = objNotesDatabase.CreateDocument
    'Code here to send email

Finally
    If Not objNotesItem Is Nothing Then
        objNotesItem = Nothing
    End If
    If Not objNotesRichTextItem Is Nothing Then
        objNotesRichTextItem = Nothing
    End If
    If Not objNotesDocument Is Nothing Then
        objNotesDocument = Nothing
    End If
    If Not objNotesDatabase Is Nothing Then
        objNotesDatabase = Nothing
    End If
    If Not objNotesSession Is Nothing Then
        objNotesSession = Nothing
    End If
End Try
```

This code is in a method that gets called repeatedly for a number of emails that have to sent, which runs fine for quite a while (dozens of emails), but eventually, the CreateObject line fails with exception:

```
System.Exception: Cannot create ActiveX component.
```

Subsequent calls to the method fail with:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {29131539-2EED-1069-BF5D-00DD011186B7} failed due to the following error: 8007000e.
```

I got a feeling that in my Finally bock I should be doing more than just setting variables to Nothing in order to do a proper cleanup, but the Notes/Domino documentation on this is very unclear.

Please advise?

Comment: This is a common problem with programs that use heavy COM objects, the garbage collector doesn't run often enough to keep you out of trouble.  Setting the variables to Nothing accomplishes nothing, technically you'd have to call Marshal.ReleaseComObject().  That rarely comes to a good end, the simple workaround is to count documents you create and call GC.Collect() when it reaches, say, 100.

Comment: Another option might be to only create it once and reuse it throughout your application.